# AMD (ex. Xilinx) Information Center not starting in tray mode at login following upgrade from Ubuntu 18.04 to 22.04 (via 20.04)

Tags: gnome, upgrade

Multiple versions of AMD (ex Xilinx) Vivado tools were installed on a Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS system. The system was upgraded from 18.04.6 LTS to 20.04.6 LTS and then 22.04.3 LTS, via the Ubuntu *Software Updater* GUI.

Vivado had installed the *AMD Information Center* which is started at desktop login to display notes about available updates, and to manage updates.

With the original Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS installation at desktop login then the *AMD Information Center for FPGAs & Adaptive SoCs* dialog was displayed in the middle of the screen and could be interacted with. E.g. closed after finding no updates were available.

Having upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS at desktop login then the AMD Information Center wasn't displaying correctly:

1. There is an icon in the task bar, but can't interact with it. The Quit option doesn't work and no other options:

   [image: screenshot of icon in system tray]
2. There is the following icon in the top-left of the screen which is partially hidden by the task bar, and can't interact with the icon:

   [image: partially obscured icon in top left of screen]
3. Had to kill the non-responsive *AMD Information Center* from a shell:

```
$ pkill -f xic
```

Answer (score 0):

There is the following file which starts the AMD Information Center automatically at login:

```
$ cat ~/.config/autostart/Xilinx\ Information\ Center.desktop 
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Type=Application
Name=Xilinx Information Center
Comment=Xilinx Information Center
Icon=/opt/Xilinx/xic/data/images/xlnx_logo.png
Exec=/opt/Xilinx/xic/xic -c -t
```

Used Startup Applications Preferences to remove the `-t` option which means start in tray mode:

```
$ cat ~/.config/autostart/Xilinx\ Information\ Center.desktop 
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Type=Application
Name=Xilinx Information Center
Comment=Xilinx Information Center
Icon=/opt/Xilinx/xic/data/images/xlnx_logo.png
Exec=/opt/Xilinx/xic/xic -c
```

And the behaviour at desktop login with Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS is back to that from the original Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS, in that the *AMD Information Center for FPGAs & Adaptive SoCs* dialog was displayed in the middle of the screen and can be interacted with.

The *AMD Information Center* appears to be written in Java. I don't know enough about Java GUI programming and *tray mode* to determine if the change in behaviour is due to a bug in the *AMD Information Center* or a change to the (GNOME?) desktop between Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS and Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS.